# How to inject the same bean instance into multiple beans

Tags: java, spring

I have an interesting problem I'm hoping you can help me with:

I have a bean called `AContainer`. It contains two beans, `PartA` and `PartB`. `PartA` and `PartB` need to share a bean which I'll call `PartX`.

My application will create multiple `AContainer`s, each with their own `PartA` and `PartB` implementations. Each `PartA` and `PartB` pair, however, will need to share a `PartX`.

As I see it, if I make PartX a singleton, every `PartA`/`PartB` pair will share the same `PartX` (so I can't do that). If I make them prototypes, however, `PartA` and `PartB` will get their own individual `PartX` instances. Is there some third option that would allow me to set this up with Spring?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using *Singleton*?

Comment: how do you create multiple `AContainer`s

Comment: @PaulVargas - He's carefully **not** using *Singleton*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK Spring cannot handle custom scope injections for you. You will need to inject an instance of `PartX` manually for `PartA` and `PartB` in `AContainer`. One way to do is obtaining a single instance of `PartX` (prototype scoped) in the `@PostConstruct` of `AContainer` and then inject this instance in `PartA` and `PartB`:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AContainer {

    @Autowired
    private PartA partA;
    @Autowired
    private PartB partB;
    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        PartX partX = beanFactory.getBean("partX"); //name assumed
        partA.setPartX(partX);
        partB.setPartX(partX);
    }
    //rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Spring _can_ handle custom scopes, but this is a bit more complicated since there doesn't seem to be a relation between A and B other than the X. You'd have to find a way to mark pairs of A and B instances and relate them to an X. This doesn't seem easy. A suggestion for your proposal: Make the `X` bean a prototype. Then use constructor injection to inject the A, B, and X beans into the constructor. You can then call the setters. In this way, you don't need to inject the bean factory and, IMO, you have a cleaner relation between the A, B, and X.